# ClassCastException with findFragmentById

Tags: android-fragments

I try to get a specific Fragment with:

```
RohwareFragmentMatlist fragment =    (RohwareFragmentMatlist)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.lagerfragment);
```

But I get an error from eclipse with this message:

> Cannot cast from Fragment to RohwareFragmentMatlist

The Activity starts with:

```
public class RohwareActionBar extends FragmentActivity {...
```

The RohwareFragmentMatlist is defined as follows:

```
public class RohwareFragmentMatlist extends ListFragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{...
```

The Fragment is defined this way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:name="de.ypssoft.RohwareFragmentMatlist"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0px" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lagerfragment" 
android:layout_margin="5dip" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
>
</fragment>
<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/details" 
android:layout_weight="3"
android:layout_width="0px" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Doesn't it work to get a Fragment via "getFragmentById" using ListFragment?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510771/looking-for-wrong-fragment-class-with-android-compatibility-library) .
Since I'm using compatibility package v4 I have to use

> RohwareFragmentMatlist fragment =    (RohwareFragmentMatlist)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.lagerfragment);

instead of

> RohwareFragmentMatlist fragment =    (RohwareFragmentMatlist)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.lagerfragment);

Comment: Thank you! I was fighting with this for some time and was ready to start a whole new approach. This little tidbit fixed me right up.