# Android fragment is not showing up

Tags: android, fragment

I have the following codes in my android application:

main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="activity" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.hugo.test.FragmentA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragmenta.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="helloA" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentA.java :

```
package com.hugo.test;

//some imports here

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);
    }
}
```

FragmentActivity.java :

```
    package com.hugo.test;

    //some imports here

public class FragmentActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

The layout of the activity should display "activity" and the fragment should display "helloA". When I run my project I only see "activity", so it seems to me that the fragment is ignored at all.

The error I see is :

```
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hugo.test/com.hugo.test.FragmentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:245)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1780)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at com.hugo.test.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:11)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     ... 11 more
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.hugo.test.fragmenta: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:500)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:468)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4132)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     ... 20 more
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hugo.test.fragmenta in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jochen.test-1.apk]
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:490)
12-19 09:01:05.370: E/AndroidRuntime(1352):     ... 23 more
```

Because of that error I added a constructor to FragmentA.java

```
public FragmentA()
{

}
```

This error is not gone, the fragment still doesn't show up, same behavior as before. Anyone an idea?

Comment: I just saw that in onCreateView() the ViewGroup container is null, might that be an issue? how to avoid it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was due to the 0dp I haven't seen that when I copied that part from the Android page.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Activity {
```

should be

```
public class FragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

This is also discussed at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510771/looking-for-wrong-fragment-class-with-android-compatibility-library)

Comment: I am not using any compatibility package, pure Honeycomb and above. Hence I am not able to use FragmentActivity, which comes into the system only with that compatibility package to my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I'm not aware of your Honeycomb environment in the first place, but yes, as you said the fragment widget requires width greater than 0dp.

Answer (score 1):

use this, it works for me

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);
    return returnView;

}
```

}