# FragmentPagerAdapter Exists Only In Android.Support.V4.App (and not Android.App)

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, fragmentpageradapter

I cannot find find FragmentPagerAdapter within Android.App.

I do not want to use the Fragment's from Android.Support.V4.App, as my target API is
14 and higher (Android 4.0 and up). So, I want to just use plain of Android.App.Fragments,
and there associated classes.

I only have found it within Android.Support.V4.App, but this doesn't suffice
for me b/c I'm trying to use Android.App.Fragment's (not Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment's)
and there related classes within Android.App (not Android.Support.V4.App), and my code wont
compile if I derive my pager from FragmentPagerAdapter if its from the Support library,
because of the resulting type mismatch's between Android.App and Android.Support.V4.App.

Just as with the case here [Cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383247/cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-fragment), is there a "normal" pager (PagerAdapter) class I should be using in
place of FragmentPagerAdapter or something (just like you derive from normal Activity, and
not FragmentActivity, when targeting API 11 or higher).

Here is the sample code I'm working with (its the FragmentPagerSupport.cs file within the Support4.sln solution from the MonoDroid examples found at https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Support4).

I've commented out the lines that referenced Android.Support.V4.App and replaced them with
code that references Android.App.  There is no FramePagerAdapter outside of Android.Support.V4.App that I could find, and I really need it).

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
//using Android.Support.V4.App;
//using Android.Support.V4.View;

namespace Support4
{
    [Activity (Label = "@string/fragment_pager_support")]
    [IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionMain}, Categories = new[]{ "mono.support4demo.sample" })]
    //public class FragmentPagerSupport : FragmentActivity
        public class FragmentPagerSupport : Activity
    {
        const int NUM_ITEMS = 10;
        MyAdapter adapter;
        ViewPager pager;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.fragment_pager);

            //adapter = new MyAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
                        adapter = new MyAdapter(FragmentManager);

            pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
            pager.Adapter = adapter;

            var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.goto_first);
            button.Click += (sender, e) => {
                pager.CurrentItem = 0;  
            };
            button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.goto_last);
            button.Click += (sender, e) => {
                pager.CurrentItem = NUM_ITEMS - 1;
            };
        }

                // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????
                // - where is FragmentPagerAdapter 
                // ?????????????????????????????????????????????????

        protected class MyAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter 
        {
            public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
            {
            }

            public override int Count {
                get {
                    return NUM_ITEMS;
                }
            }

            public override Fragment GetItem (int position)
            {
                return new ArrayListFragment(position);
            }


        }

        protected class ArrayListFragment : ListFragment
        {
            int num;

            public ArrayListFragment()
            {
            }

            public ArrayListFragment(int num)
            {
                var args = new Bundle();
                args.PutInt("num", num);
                Arguments = args;
            }

            public override void OnCreate (Bundle p0)
            {
                base.OnCreate (p0);

                num = Arguments != null ? Arguments.GetInt("num") : 1;
            }

            public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
                var tv = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);
                tv.Text = "Fragment #" + num;
                return v;
            }

            public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle p0)
            {
                base.OnActivityCreated (p0);

                ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Cheeses.cheeseStrings);
            }

            public override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                Console.WriteLine ( "Item clicked: " + id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one that is in `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`. Not sure if that'll help you, but...

Comment: PearsonArtPhoto Not sure since there is no Android.Support.V13.View namespace (in MonoDroid anyway). I'd rather not use the support library at all, but I don't think its possible as of yet.

Comment: Looks like ViewPager exists only in the support library as well...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html The Class Overview section pretty much sums up this predicament - "Note this class is currently under early design and development. The API will likely change in later updates of the compatibility library, requiring changes to the source code of apps when they are compiled against the newer version."

Comment: Another excerpt from the docs http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html "The support library for v4 provides access to several classes introduced with Android 3.0 and beyond, plus some updated version of existing classes, and even some APIs that currently don't exist in the Android platform". However, why would they ever leave such an important piece of the Fragment "API" in the support library exclusively, where the remaining of it exists outside if it. Maybe an oversight ?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Yup, that was the one that actually fixed it. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: @SamusArin Yes. If your minSdk is greater than 11 you should use android.support.v13 .

Answer (score 203, accepted):

There is one that is in [`android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), which should do what you want it to do. It's a FragmentPagerAdapter for non-support fragments.

**Android Studio Installation**

Please add follow Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
}
```

Comment: There is a mess in a sense that you cannot use nested fragments and getChildFragmentManager() in the support lib 13.

Comment: use compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+' for gradle build

Comment: my android studio does not resolve `import  android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;` any idea? sure have already added compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1' to gradle

Comment: `support:support-v13` has conflict with `support:design` in my case

Comment: fyi: currently v13 includes all v4 dependencies, so from a dependency saving standpoint there is no benefit

Comment: But now it is deprecated in api 27 -> to use the v4 version again. Then we have the problem again, with not way to use the none support lib Fragment

Answer (score 16):

Ugh, you just need to use the FragmentPagerAdapter from the V13 support library

```
Android.Support.V13.App.FragmentPagerAdapter
```

Then all other Fragment related classes can be used from the "normal" libraries/namespaces, with the exception of ViewPager, but that's no big deal.

---

Here's a sample for completeness (modified "Support4" example from https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Java.Lang;

using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Fragment = Android.App.Fragment;

namespace Support4
{
    [Activity (Label = "@string/fragment_pager_support")]
    [IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionMain}, Categories = new[]{ "mono.support4demo.sample" })]
    public class FragmentPagerSupport : Activity
    //public class FragmentPagerSupport : FragmentActivity
    {
        const int NUM_ITEMS = 4;

        protected MyAdapter _pagerAdapter;
        protected ViewPager _viewPager;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.fragment_pager);

            List<Fragment> fragments = new List<Fragment>();

            // *** MonoDroid 4.2.7 letter case bug *** make's first letter lower.

            //string typeName = typeof(Fragment1).FullName;
            string typeName = "support4." + typeof(Fragment1).Name;

            fragments.Add(Fragment.Instantiate(this, typeName));
            fragments.Add(Fragment.Instantiate(this, typeName));
            fragments.Add(Fragment.Instantiate(this, typeName));
            fragments.Add(Fragment.Instantiate(this, typeName));

            //adapter = new MyAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
            _pagerAdapter = new MyAdapter(FragmentManager, fragments);

            _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.view_pager);
            _viewPager.Adapter = _pagerAdapter;
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }

        protected class MyAdapter : Android.Support.V13.App.FragmentPagerAdapter
        {
            private List<Fragment> _fragments;

            public override Java.Lang.Object  InstantiateItem(View p0, int p1)
            {
                return base.InstantiateItem(p0, p1);
            }

            public MyAdapter(Android.App.FragmentManager fm)
                : base(fm)
            {

            }

            //public MyAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments)
            //    : base(fm)
            public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments)
                : base(fm)
            {
                _fragments = fragments;
            }

            public override int Count {
                get {
                    return NUM_ITEMS;
                }
            }

            //public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int p0)
            public override Fragment GetItem(int p0)
            {
                return _fragments[p0];
            }

            public override float GetPageWidth(int p0)
            {
                //return base.GetPageWidth(p0);
                //base.GetPageWidth(p0);

                return (float)(0.5f);
            }
        }
    }

    //public class Fragment1 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    public class Fragment1 : Fragment
    {
        int num;

        private static int _colorIndex = 0;
        private static Android.Graphics.Color[] _colors = new[] { Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua, Android.Graphics.Color.DarkViolet,
        Android.Graphics.Color.Coral, Android.Graphics.Color.Bisque};

        public Fragment1()
        {
        }

        public Fragment1(int num)
        {
            var args = new Bundle();
            args.PutInt("num", num);
            Arguments = args;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle p0)
        {
            base.OnCreate(p0);

            num = Arguments != null ? Arguments.GetInt("num") : 1;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.aaaaa, container, false);

            TextView tv = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);
            tv.Text = "# " + _colorIndex;
            tv.SetBackgroundColor(_colors[_colorIndex++]);

            return v;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle p0)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(p0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<!-- Top-level content view for the simple fragment sample. -->

<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="4dip"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="700dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFCCFFFF">

    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      android:background="#FF335555"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is a mess in a sense that you cannot use nested fragments and getChildFragmentManager() in the support lib 13.

Answer (score 2):

Add this dependecy to the gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
```

And use [`android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) like this (I simply modified the official demo project in android studio: file → new → new project → next → next → tabbed activity → next → finish):

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

/** A simple FragmentPagerAdapter that returns a MapFragment and a PreferenceFragment. */
public class MainActivityAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private PreferencesFragment preferencesFragment;

    public MainActivityAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        preferencesFragment = new PreferencesFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mapFragment;
            case 1:
                return preferencesFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per 2019 with AndroidX

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue. My solution was to copy the code from android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter, then change the imported Fragment class to android.app.Fragment. Afterwards do other minor adaptions to remove all errors. To my surprise it works perfectly.
IMO this is simpler than adding a support library that you do not really need.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * PagerAdapter for ViewPager that is compatible with android.app.Fragment.
 */
abstract class FragmentPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;
    private Fragment mCurrentPrimaryItem = null;

    /**
     * Returns a unique id for the fragment on the given position.
     * For example this can be the view id that is used on the page's fragment.
     * @param position The page index
     * @return An id that is unique with respect to the pages in the adapter.
     */
    abstract long getItemId(int position);

    /**
     * Returns the fragment for the given page index.
     * @param position The page index
     * @return The fragment
     */
    abstract Fragment getItem(int position);

    public FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super();
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }

        final long itemId = getItemId(position);

        // Do we already have this fragment?
        String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if (fragment != null) {
            mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
        } else {
            fragment = getItem(position);
            mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                    makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
        }
        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        mCurTransaction.detach((Fragment) object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReferenceEquality")
    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
            }
            mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        if (mCurTransaction != null) {
            mCurTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            mCurTransaction = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return ((Fragment)object).getView() == view;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
    }
}
```