# Android : ListFragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I want to create one screen in application where i have list of items (ListFragment) which have one button named `"Next"`.

For a Example I have 50 items in my `arraylist`, here i want to load first 5 or 6 items for first list when user click on next then user can see next 6 to 12 items. this manner it will continue till 50. This `List fragment` should not have vertical scroll.

These 50 items is dynamic sometimes it would be 5 only sometimes 10 or sometimes 25.

So here how can i load this type of view in `ListFragment with viewpager`.?

Please some one guide to how can i achieve this.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Start here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html and download the FragmentBasics.zip project.  Implementing Fragments in a ViewPager is not trivial so make sure you read and understand what's going in the Android docs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example

Comment: Here is a succinct example in Mono/C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501424/fragmentpageradapter-exists-only-in-android-support-v4-app-and-not-android-app

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an ArrayAdapter for your ListView and give it the 6 to 12 items you want to display.

When the user clicks on 'next', you can replace the items in the ArrayAdapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() on it, to let it redraw itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i can not do auto manage those things? I have to do manually by code to set 1 to 6 items and 6 to 12 items etc.  As my items are not fixed sometimes only 2 items would also be there.

Comment: You can add as many items to the adapter as you like, if you have 50, set 6 to 12, and load other items on 'next'. If you have only two items, just set the two. Not much different to using multiple lists and a ViewPager, but much simpler.