# How to change Activity in Android with Xamarin?

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin

I'm new with Xamarin and I'm tring to create an Android App.

I have created a 2 `Views` related to 2 different `Activities`. The first `Activity`, name it `A`, has a button that launches the second `Activity`, name it `B`.

`B` has an `EventHandler` that is connected, in the `OnCreate` method, to `A`'s `Event`. The `EventHandler` print on console a string, that's it.

if I launch the app and press the `A`'s button, the `B` activity appears. Now, if I press the `Back` button the `A` Activity appears again, after that I press the button again and the `B` Activity appears **but** this is a new `B` Activity istance and not the previous one. I can see that because the `OnCreate` method is called twice and because I can see on console that the event is called twice.

If I repeat this many times I can see the same string printed on console repeated many times. I would like to have only one instance of any activity, so I need to change view without creating more istances of one activity that was already created or destroy the `B` Activity when the `Back` button is pressed.

How can I do that? is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't link the two activities, or better, you really shouldn't. If you need shared data then go through static properties (perhaps in a separate static class).
Read about [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [activity launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). Note that you are probably creating a wrong flow though.

Comment: How can I `Resume` an Activity? I already tested the various _Launch Mode_ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to get what you want (having two "Activities" of which the instance is *always* the same when you are switching between them), you basically need to use Fragments instead of Activities, in a FragmentPagerAdapter.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/

[FragmentPagerAdapter Exists Only In Android.Support.V4.App (and not Android.App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501424/fragmentpageradapter-exists-only-in-android-support-v4-app-and-not-android-app)

Comment: Thinks that `A` is a menu, in which you can go throw different things, and `B` is one of those things that opens up when the user selects a button in the menu activity.. So I will not have only 2 activities but _n_ .