# Using FragmentStatePagerAdapter WITHOUT support library

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I would like to know is it possible to use the class FragmentStatePagerAdapter or its equivalent without the support library?

I know how to use native fragments in place of those from the support library and many other classes have their similar equivalents, but I can't find what should be used instead of this class.

I basically want to extend it for using it in my adapter like this

```
public class ImageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {...
```

Comment: yes, it is possible ... you have to copy all necessary code from support library to your project .... but you can use `android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead `android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (and use supportv13 library) ... `android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is using native Fragments not the one from support ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I totally forgot about v13... But I actually  wanted to simplify my project structure by removing support libraries and the like. I still can't believe there is no class equivalent inside android.app package because Fragment class is already there along with android.app.FragmentManager  but no adapters...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I presume you've read the `ViewPager` [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), but just in case:

> This class is currently under early design and development. The
>   API will likely change in later updates of the compatibility library,
>   requiring changes to the source code of apps when they are compiled
>   against the newer version.

I too was initially baffled as to why the PagerAdapter classes were not a part of the `android.app.*` namespace. As they are still undergoing refinement, they have been included in the support libraries so that those libraries can be updated frequently as changes are introduced (AOSP updates are far less convenient and thus occur on a far less frequent basis). It seems that once the Android team gives final shape to the `ViewPager` and all its related classes, they will become a part of the AOSP. Even the `ViewPager` class itself is still a part of the V4 support library. So what you want should be possible in the near future ... :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you mentioned adding it to the AOSP code will require users to have that new version of android so by near feature I would think more along the lines of 2 years... I don't get why they haven't finalised the API and just put the code that was in the support library 2 years ago.

Comment: They could have even done that awful compatibility trick thy do sometimes when they document "This method currentl does nothing but will do something in the feature/done in the past" with methods they are planing to add although I doubt they will add new functionalities and the changes will probably be on performance and memory optimisations.