# LoaderManager and CursorLoader not working in ViewPager's Fragment

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have a Fragment called `AllSongsFragment` in a `ViewPager`. The parent `Activity` extends `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

I'm trying to implement `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader` to get a cursor asynchronously. Below is the `AllSongsFragment`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;

public class AllSongsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "YAYYYY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST};
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // TODO
}
}
```

My problem is that onCreateLoader() or any of the LoaderManager callback methods aren't getting called. The app doesn't crash either and there is no Exceptions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My original code is actually working. Lesson learned: Never use Toasts to confirm method calls. Instead use android.util.Log

Comment: I realize now that I wasn't calling show() on the Toast. How stupid of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the support library classes `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader`. Hence you need to use the call to the *support* `LoaderManager`.

Replace

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

with

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, (LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>)this);
```

Comment: It seems now that onLoaderReset() is called while destroying the activity by pressing back. If I try to make a Toast in onLoaderReset() I get a NullPointerException which must be because the activity is destroyed and the getActivity() returns null. However, onCreateLoader() is still not called. The only reason why I'm using the support library is because it's not possible to use the FragmentPagerAdapter without it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it should work now. I don't get why its not working for you. Any more details ?

Comment: I don't know of any other code that is relevant to the problem. On another thread, someone who had the same setup as I do said that his problem was solved by using getLoaderManager.initLoader(). On another thread, someone says that LoaderManager never works without calling forceLoad(). So I'm trying to figure out how to call the method.

Comment: It's actually working with my original code. My problem was that I was using Toasts to confirm method calls and the Toasts weren't getting created. Another problem is that my BaseAdapter is not updating itself with the ArrayList that I create from the asynchronously loaded cursor, but it'll be for another thread. Thanks for your time, @Y.S

Comment: Hey you're welcome ... just as an aside, the call to `getLoaderManager()` will likely fail on devices with API level < 11, so you *should* use `getSupportLoaderManager()` here :) ..... also, `getLoaderManager()` certainly did not work for me on a `Nexus 5` with support `Loader`s and `LoaderManager`s ... strange :/

Comment: My app will only support devices running on ICS and above so it won't be a problem for me. I think these APIs aren't very well coded to begin with. That must be why it's not very straightforward to use them.

Comment: "these APIs aren't very well coded to begin with" - what you mean, i take it, is that you're wondering why the `PagerAdapter` classes are not yet a part of AOSP and still in the support library. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512294/using-fragmentstatepageradapter-without-support-library) question for more on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74367/discussion-between-david-heisnam-and-y-s).