# Android conflict when adding a fragment to activity class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have defined my `fragments` class as

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class UserAccountDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_account_details_fragment, container, false);
```

}}

I have defined my activity as

```
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   public class HomeScreenActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    UserAccountDetailsFragment userAccDetailsFrag = new   UserAccountDetailsFragment();

     android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments, userAccDetailsFrag );
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

The problem is i am not able to add the fragment. It says UserAccountDetailsFragment should be made a fragment. But that class already extends fragments. What am i missing here?

XML---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HomeScreenActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/fragments"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are working with support.v4 package.
you should try the below:

```
FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Note: FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction are class in support.v4 pacgage

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot mix Fragment API from regular SDK with android-support SDK.

You have to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead `getFragmentManager()`.

`getSupportFragmentManager()` returns android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.

I would also suggest to check first if your fragment is already added and in case your fragment is NOT added to the back stack use setRetainInstance(true) on your fragment.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
public class HomeScreenActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "custom_tag";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (frag == null) {
        UserAccountDetailsFragment userAccDetailsFrag = new   UserAccountDetailsFragment();
        userAccDetailsFrag.setRetainInstance(true);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments, userAccDetailsFrag, FRAGMENT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

replace by:

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

and use this on in your xml:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_relative_fragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and mention in manifest those:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and map key

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: when i changed from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager. i still get an error asking me to revert back

Comment: @D-D check you are using in your xml also this fragment support other wise it will gives you binary inflate xml error

Comment: @D-D difference in those to discussed here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/why-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment-is-conflicting

Answer (score 0):

try thi,

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
   public class HomeScreenActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    UserAccountDetailsFragment userAccDetailsFrag = new   UserAccountDetailsFragment();

     android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragments, userAccDetailsFrag );
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

this may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
      UserAccountDetailsFragment userAccDetailsFrag = new   UserAccountDetailsFragment();
                 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragments, userAccDetailsFrag).commit();
```

try this

Comment: Eclipse is asking me to revert back to android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();