# Type missmatch cannot convert from Fragment to fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I'm getting this error at the moment:

```
"type missmatch cannot convert from FragmentA to fragment".
```

Under each If statement

```
    if(arg0==0)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentA(); 
    }

if(arg0==0)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentB(); 
    }

if(arg0==0)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentC(); 
    }
```

So I'm wondering if it's something to do with my import files? As I keep having trouble with those. I'll list the Import files and then the relevant code. Could be either the method or the imports not to sure which.

Ok so here is the full code:

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main_activity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener {



    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferncesfile";

    ViewPager viewPager; 
    ActionBar actionBar; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this); 

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this); 

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Tab 3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this); 

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);
     }
    public void onTabReselected1(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        Log.d("VIVZ", "onTabReselected at "+" position "+tab.getPosition()+" name "+tab.getText());


    }

    public void onTabSelected1(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.d("VIVZ", "onTabSelected at "+" position "+tab.getPosition()+" name "+tab.getText());

    }

    public void onTabUnselected1(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.d("VIVZ", "onTabUnselected at "+" position "+tab.getPosition()+" name "+tab.getText());

    }



    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
    {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment=null; 
        if(arg0==0)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentA(); 
        }
        if(arg0==1)
        {
            fragment=new FragmentB(); 
        }
        if(arg0==2) 
        {
            fragment=new FragmentA(); 
        }
        return fragment;
    }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: post MyAdapter with imports.

Comment: Does FragmentA inherit Fragment of v4?

Comment: I thought it did but it doens't seem able to.

Comment: For sure, check you are using Fragment class of same package.

Comment: Ok so do you think a Typecast might fix the issue?

Comment: no it will not fix the issue,but you have to use the same import in all your fragment classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Check the imports in all the classes in which you are extending fragments, as `android.app.Fragment` is different from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and hence the conflict*

It may be happening because your `FragmentA` class may be extending Fragment (i.e may be  importing) old `android.app.Fragment` and the one you posted is extending the fragment class from import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`;

---

See this : [Difference between android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment)

Comment: Ok so which one should I be importing? is there a preference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment