# Android Java Toast From Fragments Error

Tags: android

I tried using a second class that extends Activity but still crashing... This is what I have

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
    private Button buttonOne ;
    private Handler handler;
    private Activity activity ;
    @Override


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragement1_layout, container, false);
        final Button button = (Button)V.findViewById(R.id.two);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)V.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setText("Hello");

            }
        });

      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return V;
    }


}
```

I can't call a a toast message from the same class that extends fragment so I created one object that extends activity for a toast message but no luck :|. Can someone here help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I can see no need for the `runOnUiThread` there? All of the `onCreateView` method is executed on the UI thread anyway.

I believe, as you mention it is crashing, this is probably a ['NPE'](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) caused by using your `activity` variable. You haven't supplied any code to suggest it is being initialised.

To get the current `Context` within a `Fragment`, be it a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or a `android.app.Fragment`, you can use `getActivity()`.

The following code should be used:

`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Should this code be only a snippet and you *do* require the `runOnUiThread`, you can just use `getActivity()` as follows:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please mark my answer accepted if it completely solves your problem (the big green tick by my answer!)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Add `import android.app.Fragment;` to your imports.

Comment: I should say I started off using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` as well but after upgrading `android.app.Fragment` should be used.

Comment: ... Unless you need the app to run on older versions of Android. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment).

Comment: If you use `this.getActivity()` within the Toast code he provided, it will attempt to find a `getActivity()` method within the anonymous Runnable class

Comment: Right, okay, but if it's called just inside `onCreateView` it will work - cause I do it all the time for debugging purposes. I didn't think about the runnable or rather I overlooked `activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`.