# The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a problem described in the title , the intention is to show the map of Google in fragment.

This is the fragment_inicio.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

This is the InicioFragment.java

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapClickListener {

private final LatLng UPV = new LatLng(39.481106, -0.340987);
private GoogleMap mapa;

// @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container,
            false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_inicio);

    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(UPV, 15));
    mapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mapa.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    mapa.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(UPV)
            .title("UPV")
            .snippet("Universidad Politécnica de Valencia")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_compass))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
    mapa.setOnMapClickListener(this);
}

private void setContentView(int fragmentInicio) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void moveCamera(View view) {
    mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(UPV));
}

public void animateCamera(View view) {
    if (mapa.getMyLocation() != null)
        mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                mapa.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mapa.getMyLocation()
                        .getLongitude()), 15));
}

public void addMarker(View view) {
    mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mapa
            .getCameraPosition().target.latitude,
            mapa.getCameraPosition().target.longitude)));
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng puntoPulsado) {
    mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(puntoPulsado).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));

}
```

}

I would appreciate any help for this error.

thanks

**EDIT**

Try what you mention me but I still dating error.

The error now tells me:

Can not cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment

The project gave me so I do not have much knowledge about appcompat_v7 nor v4, so I understand your comment v4 is better ?.

This project was brought to an example of internet and simply added the map, now they said they want to leave the position.

Is this the best way or look for another way to add google map with positioning.

Is that too much to ask an example of Fragment with GoogleMap, but not other request.

Comment: Did you import Fragment by doing `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getSupportFragmentManager()` use `getFragmentManager()`.

It looks like you are using android.app.Activity and the related Fragments and not the support Activity and Fragments provided by the v4 Support Library.

If you need to use support Fragments then refer import the Support Libraries Fragment and Activity. If not replace the Fragment Manager

For more help refer to [Fragment vs Support Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment)