# Android Fragment cannot resolve add method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, fragmentmanager

I'm kinda new on Android development. I've been watching videos from Udemy and it seems some of codes are outdated, which lead errors. When I try to add my PlaceholderFragment object to transaction, it says **"Cannot resolve method add.."**,in addition to that, at the else statement it says **"Incompatible types"**.However the **taskFragment** object is inheriting from the Fragment class and **findFragmentByTag** returns **Fragment** type. Here is the structure of code.

Here I try use getSupportFragmentManager method to begin transaction.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        taskFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(taskFragment, "MyFragment").commit();

    } else {
        taskFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment");
    }
    taskFragment.startTask();
}
```

I have a class which extends Fragment:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    TechCrunchTask downloadTask;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void startTask() {
        if (downloadTask != null)
            downloadTask.cancel(true);
        else {
            downloadTask = new TechCrunchTask();
            downloadTask.execute();
        }
    }

}
```

TechCrunchTask class is like this. 'L' is a custom class which logs the messages and shows toasts. It is irrelevant I assume.

```
 public static class TechCrunchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String downloadURL = "http://http://feeds.feedburner.com/techcrunch/android?format=xml";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(downloadURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            ProcessXML(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            L.m(e + "");
        }
    }
```

This is the ProcessXML method:

```
  public void ProcessXML(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element rootElement = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
        L.m("" + rootElement.getTagName());

    }
```

Here is the list of imported packages:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.Parser;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
```

And this is the inside of the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

I guess this is about the version of support class. Mine is v7 as you see. How these can be solved. Thanks for help!

Comment: try to change `import android.app.Fragment;`  to  `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in  your `Fragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Courtesy To Md

Use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead `import android.app.Fragment`

[android.support.v4.app.Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) is the Fragment class in the android support library, which is a compatibility package that allows you to use some of the newer features of Android on older versions of Android.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment)

Please add this in your gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
```

Comment: Also add  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'` in `dependency`

Comment: @MD Yes yes .Nice observations .Cheers