# Why Android Fragment showing incompatible?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I going to add a fragment to an Activity . But its shows following problems . May be it's not compatible .Has there any solution ?

```
    media/arifhasnat/1ED0E5663F78E3C1/
AjkerDeal/CustomNavigation/MyApplication/
app/src/main/java/navigationdrawer/arifhasnat
/com/androidcustomnavigationdrawer/
MainActivity.java:22: error: incompatible types:
 FragmentOne cannot be converted to Fragment
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_one, new FragmentOne()).commit();
```

Here my code: Its the Main Activity where i called Fragment class

```
   package navigationdrawer.arifhasnat.com.androidcustomnavigationdrawer;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.nav);


            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_one, new FragmentOne()).commit();


        }

    }
```

Fragment :

```
package navigationdrawer.arifhasnat.com.androidcustomnavigationdrawer;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by arifhasnat on 1/5/16.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
        return view;


    }
}
```

Comment: bacause`Fragment` class from compat library is not derived from `Fragment` class from android SDK

Answer (score 2):

Your `FragmentOne` extends from `android.app.Fragment`, while your `MainActivity` use the **support library** `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Take a look at [Difference between android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment).

Answer (score 2):

`FragmentOne` inherits from `android.app.Fragment`, apparent from the `import` declaration at the top of your class file:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Conversely, your `FragmentTransaction` is from the support library:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

The two types are incompatible. To resolve the issue, change the import declaration for `FragmentOne` so that it reads `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

So Here the answer.

i have replace

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

In the Class: where i have imported an wrong package library

```
package navigationdrawer.arifhasnat.com.androidcustomnavigationdrawer;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by arifhasnat on 1/5/16.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
        return view;


    }
}
```