# Difference in usage of android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Firstly, I am aware of the existence of this highly voted question -

[Difference between android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment)

However, the answers here discusses more on when to use them (i.e. support `Fragment`s for API 4+ and app `Fragment`s for API 11+) than what are the differences in their behaviors and usages.

I'd like to know what are the advantages or disadvantages of using either when developing for a min SDK where both of them are supported (e.g. 16+) and what are the new features supported in app `Fragment`s and not in support `Fragment`s.

Comment: "what are the new features supported in app Fragments and not in support Fragments" -- AFAIK, there are none. If anything, it is the inverse: the `support-v4` fragments will have things that might not exist in native fragments on older API levels. For example, nested fragments were added to native fragments starting with API Level 17. if you need nested fragments (and heaven help you if you do), with a `minSdkVersion` of 16, you would need to use the `support-v4` fragment implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you the logic behind each of Google's changes, but per Google documentation at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v4-fragment:

> The v13 support library provides a FragmentCompat class. The v4
>   Fragment class is a standalone class that provides bugfixes which were
>   added in later platform versions, whereas the v13 FragmentCompat class
>   provides compatibility shims for the framework implementation of the
>   Fragment class.

So to summarize you are basically getting bug fixes by using the support version.

At https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment it says:

> The main differences when using this support version instead of the
>   framework version are:
>
> - Your activity must extend FragmentActivity
> - You must call getSupportFragmentManager() to get the FragmentManager

Using an online diff tool I can see the following differences in the API (not exhaustive) as of support library 28.0.0-alpha1 vs framework API level 28:

- In the support version `getActivity` returns a `FragmentActivity` instead of an `Activity` and the support version docs explain that the function may return null if the fragment is associated with a context
- Functions which operate on transitions such as `getReenterTransition` return `Object` in the support version instead of `ObjectTransition`
- The support version added the following functions: `getLifecycle`, `getViewModelStore`, `onCreateAnimation`, `requireActivity`, `requireContext`, `requireFragmentManager`, `requireHost`
- The `onInflate` method which takes an `Activity` parameter is deprecated

I see no notable difference in `FragmentManager` or `FragmentTransaction` to speak of other than:

- In the support version `setAllowOptimization` is deprecated and the authors say `setReorderingAllowed` is the replacement

To summarize the only major difference I see is that it appears that the support `Fragment` need not be associated with an `Activity` but the framework Fragment seems to require an associated Activity to function properly.