# why method getBackStackEntryCount always return 0

Tags: java, android

I need to count my fragment, I used getbackstackentrycount, but it always return 0. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

here my code `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.bams.taskagain;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bams.taskagain.Fragment.FragmentOne;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fragOne);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, new FragmentOne()).addToBackStack("aa").commit();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

and here is my `fragment` class

```
package com.example.bams.taskagain.Fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.bams.taskagain.R;

/**
 * Created by jack on 25/02/2017.
 */

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("Total back stack "+ ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container,false);

        return rootView;
       }
    }
```

can someone help me with my code?
I just want to get the BackStack count that my fragement has.

Comment: looks like you missed code of Activity

Answer (score 0):

You're using `android.app.Fragment` and `android.app.FragmentManager` but using `getSupportFragmentManager()` to get back stack entry count.

Use

```
getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()
```

`getFragmentManager()` is used if your fragment is `android.app.Fragment` and `getSupportFragmentManager()` if your fragment is `android.support.v4.fragment`.

For more info on these fragments, take a look at [Difference between android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment)

Comment: still return 0 :(

Comment: Fragment is created once the `onCreateView` is executed and rootView is returned. Move the log statement to `onViewCreated` method.