# Wrong 1st argument tpe. Found 'my.example.muhammadusman.event_App.myregistration' , required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make my fragments in my app in this case I follow one tutorial 
But I am stuck at this error

Dashboard.java

[image: **Dashboard.java**]

ViewPageAdapter

[image: **ViewPageAdapter**]

Error Log

[image: App Crash Error Log]

Comment: Your fragment "my_registration" extends class android.app.Fragment not android.v4.app.Fragment. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment

Comment: post my_registration class

Comment: not understand where I make the mistake?

Comment: Please add your code & errors as text, not images. Images cannot be found with search functionality and are therefore quite often useless for other users. It might also be useful to add link to that one tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `my_registration extends Fragment`
and this fragment should be

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Add `viewPager.setAdapter(adapter)` after calling `AddFragment` method.
like this:

```
adapter.AddFragment(..); // add first fragment 
adapter.AddFragment(..); // add second fragment
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: I did this but app is get crash on start?

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: Error Log Posted

Comment: Thanks, My problem is Solved!!