# What to use in Android API 28 now that fragments are deprecated

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android development. Our teachers are telling us we should develop our app (which is a personal task) should make use of fragments. Now in API28 fragments are deprecated. Why is that exactly? What should you use now? I find a lot of different opinions on different things in Android development and as a newby it's hard to find what the good practices are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's only native fragments that are being deprecated. Use the compatibility library fragments and all will be well. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment) for more info about the difference between native and compatibility fragments. From the [docs for `android.app.fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment):

> This class was deprecated in API level 28.
>
> Use the [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) for consistent behavior across all devices and access to [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile there's also [androidx.fragment.app.](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary)`Fragment`,

which will supersede the [android.support.v4.app](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary).`Fragment`.