# Why is ListFragment working without the ListView tag?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` working without the `ListView` tag in the XML file resource.

According the following reference, a `ListFragment` needs an XML file with the `ListView` tag:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment

However, the code below is working fine without one. Does this thread explain why?

[Difference between android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109017/difference-between-android-app-fragment-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment)

Also, I'm working with `android-support-v4-app-fragment` and `android-app-fragment`.

Thanks.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/newFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">    
    </FrameLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.newFrame, fragmentA, "fragmentA");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

ListFragment:

```
public class FragmentA extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String dataArray[] = new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three",};

        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataArray);

        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Because it has a ListView as `android.R.id.list` I would think.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works is because onCreateView in the ListFragment creates a simple ListView for you.

Here is the Android source code for ListFragment:

```
/**
 * Provide default implementation to return a simple list view.  Subclasses
 * can override to replace with their own layout.  If doing so, the
 * returned view hierarchy <em>must</em> have a ListView whose id
 * is {@link android.R.id#list android.R.id.list} and can optionally
 * have a sibling view id {@link android.R.id#empty android.R.id.empty}
 * that is to be shown when the list is empty.
 * 
 * <p>If you are overriding this method with your own custom content,
 * consider including the standard layout {@link android.R.layout#list_content}
 * in your layout file, so that you continue to retain all of the standard
 * behavior of ListFragment.  In particular, this is currently the only
 * way to have the built-in indeterminant progress state be shown.
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.list_content,
            container, false);
}
```

[Source code for ListFragment](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ListFragment.java)

The file list_content.xml contains the following ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If however your code were to override onCreateView in the ListFragment to provide a custom layout, then your layout would need to explicitly declare a ListView.

*Note: It is probably worth mentioning that ListView is currently classified as a "Legacy" view by Android Studio. The majority of new apps should currently be using a RecyclerView under most circumstances.*

The following Android Studio command will create a fully working RecyclerView sample list for you:

```
File -> New -> Fragment (List)
```

[It currently creates a list derived from Fragment not ListFragment]