# Class cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment on FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting the following error trying to start an activity with a Fragment

```
08-09 13:50:57.070: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.zap.imoveis/br.com.zap.imoveis.ui.ResultadoBusca}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:133)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
        at br.com.zap.imoveis.ui.ResultadoBusca.onCreate(ResultadoBusca.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.zap.imoveis.ui.ResultadoBuscaMapa cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        ... 22 more
```

Despite of what it says here:
[Cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383247/cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-fragment)

I have this error even though my Activity extends from  `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, error messages some times are very misleading. I've almost rebuilt my application to find out that during a refactor I have accidentally deleted this line o code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

on the `onCreate` method of my activity.

Comment: does it solve your problem? question asked and answered 17 secs!

Comment: @Raghunandan http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: i just want to know if it solves your problem. but you only have log information and no code

Comment: Yes it did, thank you. But I cannot accept it before 2 days :)