# the application had stopped unexpectedly on android emulator

Tags: android

this is my first program and when I tried to run it, there was an error message (The application (process juz.amma) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.) I dont know what slould I do. I hope all of you could help me.

this is my error logcat:

```
   05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{juz.amma/juz.amma.juzamma}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: juz.amma.juzamma in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/juz.amma-1.apk]
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: juz.amma.juzamma in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/juz.amma-1.apk]
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-13 21:09:25.232: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     ... 11 more
```

sorry and this is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="juz.amma"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/home1">
        <activity android:name=".juzamma" android:label="@string/home1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
                <activity android:name=".about"
                    android:label="@string/about">
                </activity>  
                    <activity android:name=".juz"
                    android:label="@string/juz">
                </activity> 
                 <activity android:name=".abasa"
                    android:label="@string/abasa">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".adduha"
                    android:label="@string/adduha">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".afil"
                    android:label="@string/afil">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".aladiyat"
                    android:label="@string/aladiyat">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".alail"
                    android:label="@string/alail">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".alala"
                    android:label="@string/alala">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".alalaq"
                    android:label="@string/alalaq">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".alasr"
                    android:label="@string/alasr">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".albalad"
                    android:label="@string/albalad">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".albayyinah"
                    android:label="@string/albayyinah">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".alburuj"
                    android:label="@string/alburuj">
                </activity>
            <activity android:name=".alfajr"
                    android:label="@string/alfajr">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alfalaq"
                    android:label="@string/alfalaq">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alfatihah"
                    android:label="@string/alfatihah">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".algasyiyah"
                    android:label="@string/algasyiyah">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alhumazah"
                    android:label="@string/alhumazah">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alikhlas"
                    android:label="@string/alikhlas">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alinfitar"
                    android:label="@string/alinfitar">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alinsyirah"
                    android:label="@string/alinsyirah">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alisyiqaq"
                    android:label="@string/alisyiqaq">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".alkafirun"
                    android:label="@string/alkafirun">
                </activity>         
                     <activity android:name=".alkausar"
                    android:label="@string/alkausar">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".allahab"
                    android:label="@string/allahab">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".almaun"
                    android:label="@string/almaun">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".almutaffifin"
                    android:label="@string/almutaffifin">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".alqadr"
                    android:label="@string/alqadr">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".alqariah"
                    android:label="@string/alqariah">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".annaba"
                    android:label="@string/annaba">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".annas"
                    android:label="@string/annas">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".annasr"
                    android:label="@string/annasr">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".annaziat"
                    android:label="@string/annaziat">
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".asysyams"
                    android:label="@string/asysyams">
                </activity>
            <activity android:name=".attakasur"
                    android:label="@string/attakasur">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".attakwir"
                    android:label="@string/attakwir">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".attariq"
                    android:label="@string/attariq">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".attin"
                    android:label="@string/attin">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".azzalzalah"
                    android:label="@string/azzalzalah">
                </activity> 
            <activity android:name=".quraisy"
                    android:label="@string/quraisy">
                </activity>     
                <activity android:name=".menu"
                    android:label="@string/menu">
                </activity> 
                <activity android:name=".zoom"
                    android:label="@string/zoom">
                </activity>     
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your layout XML

Comment: Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5402082/183203 (Inflating fragments with compatibility package) since the error is essentially the same as yours.  The answer there was to make sure your activity derives from FragmentActivity.

Comment: And Post your MainActivity.java also.

Comment: Why did you remove the key error message in your edit?

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with xml layout "Binary XML file line"
and check line 12 of your mainactivity.